# What exactly happens when a character is appended to a string literal with the '+' operator in C++?

Tags: c++, string, stl

Based on my reading, the following code:

```
string aggregate = "give" + 'n';
```

Should produce a resulting string with the value:

"given".

It instead produces garbage.  Why doesn't the following happen?

1. "give" is converted to a std::string via the constructor that takes a pointer to a character array.
2. The '+' overload that takes a std::string and a character is called, returning a new string.

I am basing my theory on [this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) man page.

Now, I have heard that the first argument to an overloaded operator isn't a candidate for constructor conversion if the operator is a member of a class.  I believe I read that in Koenig and Moo.  But, in this case I understand the '+' operator to be a non-member overload.

I realize this seems like a ridiculous over-complication, but I like to know *FOR SURE* what is happening when I write code.

Comment: Hint: `"give"` is an array and `'n'` as an integral value. And `arr[i]` is the same as `*(arr + i)`.

Comment: I guess I have a lot to learn about constructor conversion...  I could have swore that std::string auto-converted string literals.

Comment: @ncr It will, but the assignment operator has much lower priority than the addition operator; the addition will always happen first.

Comment: Aha!  I didn't realize that it was the assignment operator that invokes that constructor.  Seems so obvious now, but I was fixated on the part of code on the right side of the assignment operator...

Comment: @ncr: @meager has tricked you. :) That's not assignment, it's *initialization*. (Just because the `=` is there doesn't make it assignment.) Namely, this is *copy-initialization*. The other form of initialization, *direct-initialization*, takes the form `T x(v);` instead of `T x = v;`, the latter being equivalent to `T x(T(v));`. Note the compiler is free to omit the copy-constructor call implied by *copy-initialization*. That all said, @meager was on the right track: the expression on the right has to be evaluated *first* before initialization can occur.

Comment: @GMan Thanks, you are correct. The important thing to take away is that the right-hand-side stuff happens first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `"give" + 'n'` is evaluated first, adding `(int)'n'` to the address of the string constant `"give"`. The result of this pointer arithmatic is assigned to the string object. No error is raised because the result is of type `const char*`.

You should get used to thinking of everything on the right of the `=` as happening before the actual assignment (or initialization in this case).

You want the following:

```
// construct the string object first
std::string aggregate = "give";

// then append the character
aggregate += 'n';
```

or, explicitly build the a string object first:

```
std::string aggregate = std::string("give") + 'n';
```

Answer (score 5):

The fact that there is a `std::string` on the left side of the expression doesn't matter for the first step: `"give"` is a `const char[5]` which decays to a `const char*` and `'n'` is a `char`, that is, an integer type. Adding an integer to a pointer simply adds to the pointer's address. The result is again of type `const char*`, which is then implicitly converted to `std::string`.

Basically, your code is equivalent to:

```
const char* c = "a string" + 'n';
std::string s = c;
```

So, to achieve the desired effect, try

```
std::string s = std::string("a string") + 'n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the integer 'n' to the address of the literal "give".

Try it with:

```
string aggregate = "long string long string long string long string long string long string long string " + 'A';
```

That should illustrate what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't do what you think it does.

It takes the string literal `"give"` which then effectively degrades into a `const char[5]`, and then add the integer value of `'n'` to that pointer. It then takes that new garbage pointer and tries to make a string out of it.

You want `string aggregate = std::string("give") + 'n';`

Comment: It doesn't degrade to `const char[5]`, it *is*.